# Android Https signing parameters

Tags: android, https, restful-authentication

Good day! 
I have a trouble with sending https request from android application with signing parameters.
I have source which allows me to send secure http request, but authentification does not work.
I need to send request to some url with port number.
By using

```
HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8");
```

After this, I retrieve this parameters in string format like

```
param2=param1&param2=param2%20p - encoded format
```

Next I need take md5 hash and again introduce it in httpbody param without encoding

Example of request:

```
HTTP method - POST
Headers: Content-Length - 275
Content-Type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

параметры в HTTP body -
PHONE=2583838&ORDER_STATE_ID=31&SOURCE=улица%20Жандосова,%20188&DESTINATION=Тепличная%20улица,%202а&CLIENTID=62&SOURCE_TIME=20130807120054&IS_PRIOR=true&NOTE=This%20is%20comment&PHONE_TO_DIAL=8(701)746-90-26&CUSTOMER=Anna%20Ahmatova&signature=ed4aaef27e2d46a46f449903f3524788
```

Help me please. This post request working but everytime I have trouble with authentification